# Confusing Encryption Mode

Tags: encryption

I have an API that accepts plain-text and IV as input and I'm trying to identify the encryption mode for that API. I have already tested this API for ECB, CBC, OFB, CFB and CTR and it doesn't seem to be any of these modes. Though on first glance it appears to be padded CBC mode but if you look at my Step 3 (see below) it isn't CBC because for padded CBC mode the Step 3 output should be `C1 (first 16 byte of Step 1 ciphertext)|| C2(Step 2 cipherxtext)` where || means concatenation. Any guidance on what this mode could be will be appreciated!

````
Step 1: curl "http://dev/api/v1.0/test-1?iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&text=00000000000000000000000000000000"
{"ciphertext":"e910b119321663b062ca59d3f09a95f6282397de97904f8267638c5f234b1ee7"}

Step 2: curl "http://dev/api/v1.0/test-1?iv=e910b119321663b062ca59d3f09a95f6&text=00000000000000000000000000000000"
{"ciphertext":"b793f834eeb36c0eac275df3ba53c6e50de0df8f9b31afcb8b5eb89ebaaf3ad8"}


Step 3: curl "http://dev/api/v1.0/test-1?iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&text=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
{"ciphertext":"e910b119321663b062ca59d3f09a95f6282397de97904f8267638c5f234b1ee75bd4c7fbd2cdd9b658507be2dec68429"}```
````

Comment: Did you try all of this from the [answers to your previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85723/18298)

Comment: Yes and in addition I read on my own about all common block modes. Since I'm pretty new on this site, I don't know if I edit my original question would anyone get notified? Much would be appreciated if you could let me know what is the best way for asking related question?

Comment: You should write your question so that what you had tried from all of the solutions from your previous question by giving the link and the failed modes with reasons. Besides, your API is not disclosed, right? Also, in the first place, you should have named it. if you name it, one can know about it.

Comment: [Ciphertext stealing mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing#CBC_ciphertext_stealing)

Comment: There's ongoing discussion on this question in this [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115453), where it is appropriate.

Comment: Thank for you pointing in right direction and giving helpful tips!